# Is there a function like "timeout" that skips a command instead of killing it?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have written an infinite while-loop to run 4 scripts, two's at a time, but when a script executes it waits for it to finish, instead of looping.

```
while true; do
    script1.sh & script2.sh
    script3.sh & script4.sh
done
```

I added timeout this time, and it kills an active script. Usually each script runs for an hour.

Comment: If don't want to wait for a script to exit, just use `disown`, as in `script1.sh & disown ; script2.sh & disown`

Comment: @astronax, ...that doesn't "skip" anything. And I don't see why you'd need `disown` here at all. Noninteractive shells don't sleep waiting for backgrounded child processes to edit in the first place. (Neither do interactive ones, for that matter).

Comment: You don't run `script2.sh` or `script4.sh` in the background; the shell waits for `script2.sh` to finish before running `script3.sh` and `script4.sh`.  It doesn't repeat the loop until `script4.sh` finishes.  It isn't clear what behaviour you want.  You could run two scripts in background and then `wait` for them to finish; repeat for the second two scripts.  It isn't clear what should happen if a script takes 'too long' to complete.

Comment: @bruh : What do you mean by _skipping_ instead of killing? Taking this literally, I would understand it as travelling back in time and making sure that the offender doesn't get started in the first place. Since you most likely don't mean this, please describe the desired behaviour a little bit more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding a `PID` preventing active scripts from being ran again, each script has this added

```
    PIDFILE=$pid.pd
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
    then
      PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
      ps -p $PID > /dev/null 2>&1
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]
      then
        echo "Process already running"
        exit 1
      else
        ## rocess not found assume not running
        echo $$ > $PIDFILE
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
          echo "Could not create PID file"
          exit 1
        fi
      fi
    else
      echo $$ > $PIDFILE
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]
      then
        echo "Could not create PID file"
        exit 1
      fi
    fi

    //insert commands here

    rm $PIDFILE
```

And by running each script on background using `&`

```
while true; do
    script1.sh & script2.sh &
    sleep 1.5
    script3.sh & script4.sh &
    sleep 1.5
done
```

and `sleep` for cpu handling.
Thanks to Jonathan and Charles.